# Is it possible to automatically merge multiple sets of duplicate contacts?

Tags: contact, merge

I have >100 sets of contacts, each with its own duplicate records. I plan to merge them, but would prefer not to do it manually one contact at a time. Is there a way to get salesforce to do it all automatically?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this inside Salesforce other than writing some Apex code to handle it.  That would mean duplicating much of what the existing merge process does for your new process.

Dupblocker and DemandTools are third party products that deal with duplicates.  Dupblocker prevents users from entering duplicates. Among the many other useful parts of DemandTools is a flexible duplicate correction tool.  I've used it extensively.  It works well.

Answer (score 0):

If the contacts belong to the same account they can be merged from the account page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DupeCatcher (https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003IYLlEAO)

Its a free tool on the AppExchange, or any other, like the ones provided by Informatica Cloud